# ＃warning＃Call to undefined function 'print_r' when I copied my php file from one site to another in the same Zend

Tags: php, zend-studio, php-5.2

[image]

- I can't really understand what happened here.
  What I've done was to copy a php file to another project in the same Zend. It's a warning, not an error.
- My computer is supposed to have only one php version, so it seems nothing to do with the php version.
- the function is standard "print_r", so it seems nothing to do with the undefined function.

the code is very normal, like : print_r ( "image:" );

Comment: Always provide the full error message and also show the related code. The PHP error message contains the location of the error, take a look at the code there. If it is complicate to describe, you can improve with a screenshot for example.

Comment: Please mention the complete error message along with the code.

Comment: try this http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=415

Comment: @hakre It's a warning, not an error. And I have added a picture. check it, please.

Comment: This really is nothing to do with PHP and is a Zend IDE problem. print_r will work.

Comment: Does the code actually run? It looks like the IDE complaining about it rather than PHP itself. So I guess there's a problem with the IDE's config. (But anyway, why use `print_r` when you've got the Zend debugging tools available?)

Comment: @RakeshSharma That's the key. Yes, I used the guide you gave and dismissed my warnings of built-in functions. Really grateful! Would you mind starting a new Answer as my answer?

Comment: @SDC As I mentioned above, it does have a problem with project's config.

Comment: @EM-Creations .....I lost my .buildpath file.

Comment: @anna, you can post an answer aswell.

Comment: @Jeffrey Ok, I have posted.

Comment: glad to know it's being useful for you, and your full answer will help more people on stack

Comment: @RakeshSharma You're cool~~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> try this kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=415 – @Rakesh Sharma

To workaround this problem the user needs to manually add relevant content into the '.buildpath' file.

- Close the project (Project | Close Project).
- Open the '.buildpath' file that resides in the project's root directory with a text editor. If the file does not exist, create it.
  Paste the correct contents into the '.buildpath' file:

.buildpath contents for a PHP Project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

.buildpath contents for a Zend Framework Project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.zend.php.framework.CONTAINER"/>
</buildpath>
```

- Save the file.
- Open your project (Project | Open Project).
- Rebuild the project (Project | Clean).

**After the build process finishes, you should see no warnings for standard PHP functions.**